# Can't figure out negative lookahead expression in JS while implementing in regex

Tags: javascript

As far as I know, Negative lookahead looks to make sure the element in the search pattern is not there. A negative lookahead is used as (?!...) where the ... is the pattern that you do not want to be there. The rest of the pattern is returned if the negative lookahead part is not present.

Here's my code:

```
let str = "1Kill";

let regex = /(?!\d)/; or regex = /(?![^0-9])/;

let result = regex.test(str);
```

Here I'm getting `result = true;`
But, I don't understand why?

I have also checked for, `regex = /(?=[^0-9])/;`

I'm getting the same result. I want to check for "if the first letter in the str is a number/digit or not" but I'm unable to do that with Negative Lookahead however I'm able to do it with "`regex = /(?=^[^0-9])/;`".

Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you current regex is doing is failing to match the 1 and then matching at 1|kill because at that point it no longer has a number as your regex matches a single character in the string.

Here's an example with negative lookahead that would work: `/^(?!\D*(?:\d\D*)+$)/` The main difference here is that it matches the beginning of the string before the negative lookahead to anchor it to the beginning. Then it checks if there are any numbers anywhere in the string before the end ($).

Another possibility is: `/\d/` and then you can use that by inverting the test. This is likely the better option as it's simpler to see how it works than the negative lookahead case.

```
let str = "1Kill";

let regex = /\d/;

let result = !regex.test(str);
```

https://regex101.com/ is a very good resource for seeing what your regexes are doing and how many steps they take to do it.